# how to convert a number into unicode?

Tags: java, unicode, clojure

Usually, unicode characters can be expressed like this:

```
\u0905 => अ
```

I'm wondering how to write a function that can output the same thing:

```
(unicode "0905") => अ
```

or

```
(unicode 905) => अ
```

---

I was hoping to be able to construct a byte array representation. ie:

```
(seq (.getBytes "\u11035"))
=> (-31 -124 -125 53)
```

and then use the byte representation to construct the character.

Comment: See `Character.toChars(int)`

Comment: could you please add a description to the input you would be providing for the function expected

Comment: hmmm...here's a starter for ya: `System.out.println(String.format("\\u%04x", (int) 'अ'));`

Comment: I was hoping to be able to create the byte representation for the character.

Comment: please see update.

Comment: The question is still not clear - there are at least two possible meanings, both of which have been answered! User Scott has shown how to get a valid character from a number, and @zcaudate, you yourself have shown how to get the "byte representation" of a character. Just what are you asking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean like this?

```
(defmulti unicode class)

(defmethod unicode java.lang.String [s]
  (read-string (str "\\u" s)))

(defmethod unicode java.lang.Long [l]
  (read-string (str "\\u" (format "%04d" l))))

(unicode "0905")
;;=>\अ
(unicode 905)
;;=>\अ
```

Comment: I was hoping to get the bytes representation for the string